# Boot loader got deleted

Tags: linux, multi-boot, bootloader

I had a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu... after a while on Ubuntu, I wanted to switch to another Linux distro since Ubuntu did not fit me much at the very end. So I went for Deepin OS.

So I got on the process of installing Deepin OS to replace Ubuntu. Since my previous Ubuntu installation was one a single partition, I just deleted that partition (in the Deepin disk selection screen) and prompted for **/ (root)** install on that partition.

The process of installation did not spit any error. When it got finished I rebooted the pc (as it prompted me to do so); but then it did not boot back on the grub menu for me to choose the OS but instead, it did take me to the boot device selection menu of the BIOS. When I click on the disk hosting the dual boot sys, it says that the disk is failed!

Now I am stuck with neither a Windows OS to boot on nor a Linux System.

**NB** : *I plugged my disk hosting the dual boot system on another computer and I could see that all the partitions were all there and no data has been wiped. So the disk is not damaged in any way.*

Comment: The steps to fix the Windows bootloader depends upon whether the motherboard is BIOS or UEFI _(while your question says "BIOS" many refer to UEFI as BIOS and they're not the same things)_. **BIOS:** Boot to WinRE or WinPE > `bootrec /fixmbr` > `bootrec /fixboot` > `bootrec /rebuildbcd` _(even if no OS is found, that's okay)_; **UEFI:** the same as BIOS, except without `/fixboot` _(due to extra steps being required to modify the EFI partition, `/fixboot` will fail)_

Comment: To clear up missing facts from my question: my motherboard is using legacy BIOS. I tried the bootloader fix you stated and I kept on having Element not found.

Comment: Which did you boot, WinRE or WinPE _(WinRE is **Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment, WinPE is **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment - such as a Windows Install USB)_, and what version of Windows?  What is giving the error `Element not found`?

Comment: WinPE, Windows 10 Pro Edition 1903 update. `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` did yield `Element not found`

Comment: Please link to a screenshot showing the errors, as well as one showing the output of `diskpart` > `lis vol`.  If `/rebuildbcd` is stating no OS found, that's fine, however `/fixboot` auto rebuilds the boot files into the boot partition, which can also be found on the system partition at `Windows\Boot` _(`bcdboot` can also do the same, though I can't recall the parameters to use, but you can find the correct `bcdboot` paramaters on SuperUser or the Microsoft Docs [man page.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di))_.

Comment: [Here](https://i.ibb.co/VW6WdL0/boot-repair.jpg) is the screenshot.

Comment: `Vol 1` is the Windows boot partition, but I've never encountered the `Element not found` error before, with a search engine returning [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bootrec+element+not+found+windows+10&atb=v185-1&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

One fix is to overwrite GRUB by booting using Windows Installation disk, then choosing recovery option and then command prompt.
Now enter these commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now I am still in the same impasse as I was before, which is, stuck on the boot menu of my BIOS. It keeps on telling that disk is failed when I boot from the disk hosting my dual-boot system.

I tried some troubleshoots though:

- I supposed that it was a grub issue, as what maybe the initial grub config got messed up on the linux os replacement installation.
  So I used a live session of Linux Mint to go for a boot repair. Unfortunately, it did not fix my problems.
- Then I checked how the partition I installed the OS's on were doing. For that I used Super Grub2 Disk to manually boot to my systems. Super Grub2 could detect all the OS and I could boot manually into them (Windows and Deepin) with no problem. So the disk is definitely not failed as opposed to what boot menu says.
- Then went to Windows and made a disk check hoping that windows auto scan and repair could find any fault and resolve it... but, still no result (just a long wait).
- From there I oriented myself to boot record issues. So I did boot to WinPE and did apply procedures suggested by @JW0914 : `bootrec /fixmbr` > `bootrec /fixboot` > `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
  /fixmbr was successful but /fixboot and /rebuildbcd threw `Element not found` error.

So current state of my situation is : the two os of my dual-boot sys are fine but I have no "interface" to allow me from accessing them when I boot my PC.